# Still after convertion into grayscale can not use cv.equalizeHist() in OpenCV. Gives error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src.type() == CV_8UC1

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use `cv.equaliazeHist()` function but it gives me an error like this
 `error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:3439: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'cv::equalizeHist'`

Befor trying to use `cv.equaliazeHist()`  I have also converted the image into grayscale. Still getting this error. But If I use `cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` while reading gray scale image code runs fine though my image already is in grayscale.

```
import glob
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np

    images=[cv.imread(file) for file in sorted(glob.glob(r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\raw/*.jpg"))]
    for img in images:
        b,g,r = cv.split(img) 
        rgb_img = cv.merge([r,g,b]) 
        plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
        plt.imshow(rgb_img)
```

Conversion to grayscale:

```
di=r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\gray_scale"
for i,img in enumerate(images):
    b,g,r = cv.split(img) 
    rgb_img = cv.merge([r,g,b])
    gray_img = cv.cvtColor(rgb_img,cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    print(i)
    plt.imshow(gray_img,cmap='gray')
    cv.imwrite(di+"\\"+ "%06d.jpg" % i,gray_img.astype(np.uint8))
```

Trying to equalize:

```
images2=[cv.imread(file) for file in sorted(glob.glob(r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\gray_scale/*.jpg"))]
dir2=r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\adaptive"

for i,img in  enumerate(images2):

    ad_img=cv.equalizeHist(img)
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.imshow(ad_img,cmap='gray')
    cv.imwrite(dir2+"\\"+ "%06d.jpg" % i,ad_img.astype(np.uint8)) #adaptibe histogram
```

Comment: cv.imread() likely reads as color, since there is no meta flag in JPG to identify as grayscale. So try reading it as unchanged. See IMREAD_UNCHANGED at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80. If you know ahead of time what color type the image has, then best to be sure to read it that way.

Comment: @fmw42 I have tried it with PNG format too issue was same. However IMREAD_UNCHANGED works. I am bit afraid that about facing any other further issue.

Comment: When I read an image. I always convert to gray before processing that requires it to be gray, even if I know that it is already gray.

Comment: ok i understand! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your last block of code should not work since you are reading the images (rgb) and trying to equalize without converting to grayscale and `cv2.equalizeHist` requires a single channel.

In any case you can skip the "convert to grayscale" step by reading the pictures like this: `img = cv2.imread(file_name, 0)`

Anyway, the following code works for me, both converting to grayscale and reading directly in grayscale:

```
import cv2
file_name = '/path/to/my/picture.jpg'

# Read original image
img = cv2.imread(file_name)
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # Convert to grayscale

# Equalize and show
eq_img = cv2.equalizeHist(gray_img)
cv2.imshow('equalized', eq_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

### Read on grayscale + equalize + show ###
img = cv2.imread(file_name, 0)
eq_img=cv2.equalizeHist(img)
cv2.imshow('equalized', eq_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

(I'm using openCV 3.2.0)